# Profit calculation from last 2 year to year 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server

Respected Techie,

May any one please help me with this critical scenario.

I am trying to compare Sales value of year 2016 with sales value of (2015,2014) 
and the difference stored in alias column as Sales_growth for year 2016 , 
for year (2015,2014) the alias column be as '1'

Based on the key column month, sales_manager_code and sales_group.

but when there is no key match (month, sales_manager_code ,sales_group.)
then the alias column sales_growth 1

Formula for calculation

```
SGR = (sales(2015 or 2014)-sales (2016)) / Sales_growth(2015)
```

Table Structure and Data

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
YEAR VARCHAR (50),  
MONTH   VARCHAR (50),
SALES_MANAGER_CODE VARCHAR (50),    
SALES_GROUP VARCHAR (50),
NetProductSales VARCHAR (50)

)

INSERT @T

SELECT '2015',  '10',   '10',   'ARS',  '126431.16' UNION ALL
SELECT '2015',  '10',   '4',    '4',    '1247439.2' UNION ALL
SELECT '2014',  '11',   '4',    '2',    '1399367.53' UNION ALL
SELECT '2016',  '10',   '10',   'ARS',  '126431.16' UNION ALL
SELECT '2016',  '10',   '4',    '4',    '1247439.2' UNION ALL
SELECT '2016',  '11',   '4',    '2',    '1399367.53' UNION ALL
SELECT '2015',  '8',    '11',   '0',    '44518.18'
```

**Expected Output** Here sales_margin is alias column to store result

```
/*
YEAR    MONTH   SALES_MANAGER_CODE  SALES_GROUP NetProductSales SALES_MARGIN
2015,   10, 10, ARS,126431.16,  1
2015,   10, 4,  4,  1247439.2,  1
2014,   11, 4,  2,  1399367.53, 1
2016,   10, 10, ARS,    3565898.25, -27.20426744
2016,   10, 4,  4,  5469856.25, 3.384868016
2016,   11, 4,  2,  45268912.65,    31.34955198
2015,   8,  11, 0,  44518.18,   1



*/
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you get SalesGrowth but using a LEFT OUTER join will give you a NULL where there is no corresponding join row for which you can then use COALESCE to convert the NULL to 1.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
YEAR VARCHAR (50),  
MONTH   VARCHAR (50),
SALES_MANAGER_CODE VARCHAR (50),    
SALES_GROUP VARCHAR (50),
NetProductSales decimal( 28, 16 )

)

INSERT @T

SELECT '2015',  '10',   '10',   'ARS',  126431.16 UNION ALL
SELECT '2015',  '10',   '4',    '4',    1247439.2 UNION ALL
SELECT '2014',  '11',   '4',    '2',    1399367.53 UNION ALL
SELECT '2016',  '10',   '10',   'ARS',  126431.16 UNION ALL
SELECT '2016',  '10',   '4',    '4',    1247439.2 UNION ALL
SELECT '2016',  '11',   '4',    '2',    1399367.53 UNION ALL
SELECT '2015',  '8',    '11',   '0',    44518.18


select * 
      , COALESCE( ( tprv.NetProductSales - t16.NetProductSales ) / ???? ), 1 ) as SALES_MARGIN
from @T t16
    left outer join @T tprv on tprv.YEAR = t16.YEAR - 1
                           and tprv.MONTH = t16.MONTH
                           and tprv.SALES_MANAGER_CODE = t16.SALES_MANAGER_CODE
                           and tprv.SALES_GROUP = t16.SALES_GROUP
where t16.YEAR = 2016
```

Comment: Thanks Tony, but getting error: Incorrect syntax near ')'

Comment: The script is working fine, but it is pulling only year 2016 data. will it be possible to have all data from the table. (All 7 Rows)

Comment: Just remove the t16.YEAR = 2016